# Why isn't javascript recognizing my global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I'm setting a variable equal to an image and then calling it in a function.
This does not work because according to the javascript error console it doesn't recognize the image variable as anything but null

```
var image = document.getElementById("gc");
var duration = 3000; /* fade duration in millisecond */
var hidtime = 2000; /* time to stay hidden */
var showtime = 2000; /* time to stay visible */
var image_tracker = 1

function change() {
    if (image_tracker == 1) {
        image.src = "IMG_1267.jpg"
        image_tracker = 2
    } else if (image_tracker == 2) {
        image.src = "IMG_1239.jpg"
        image_tracker = 3
    } else {
        image.src = "IMG_1263.jpg"
        image_tracker = 1
    }
}
```

However this works fine

```
var duration = 3000; /* fade duration in millisecond */
var hidtime = 2000; /* time to stay hidden */
var showtime = 2000; /* time to stay visible */
var image_tracker = 1

function change() {

    var image = document.getElementById("gc");

    if (image_tracker == 1) {

        image.src = "IMG_1267.jpg"
        image_tracker = 2
    } else if (image_tracker == 2) {
        image.src = "IMG_1239.jpg"
        image_tracker = 3
    } else {

        image.src = "IMG_1263.jpg"
        image_tracker = 1
    }

}

var timer = setInterval('change()', 3000);
```

Comment: It could be that the HTML element with ID `gc` does not exist when you initially set `image`. Are you waiting for the page to render before you execute the JS code?

Comment: what about the others global variales like 'image_tracker' theay are recognized?

Comment: It could *only* be that the element with that `id` doesn't yet exist, given that the result of the `getElementById()` is `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, your JavaScript loads immediately, even before the DOM is completely loaded. When it tries to search for `#gc`, it can't find it because it isn't loaded into the DOM.

The solution would be to set your `image` variable when the page is completely loaded. ex.

```
var image;

window.onload = function() {
    image = document.getElementById("gc");
}

function change() {
    ....
```